# Logging http request in Spring integration http outbound gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration

is there a way (eg. interceptor) to log the request send via Spring Integration http outbound gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; inject a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` implementation into the `RestTemplate` used by the outbound gateway.

Inject the template in the gateway using the `rest-template` attribute.