# ClientHttpRequestInterceptor with a http:outbound-gateway using a request-factory attribute

Tags: spring, http, logging, spring-integration

I'm still on the subject of logging http requests.  It's been mentioned that using a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` with a `rest-template` attribute of the `http:outbound-gateway` can be an approach.

[Spring Integration AOP for Logging outbound Http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73623988/spring-integration-aop-for-logging-outbound-http-requests/73624800#73624800)

[Logging http request in Spring integration http outbound gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690843/logging-http-request-in-spring-integration-http-outbound-gateway)

However, I'm already using `request-factory` on my `http:outbound-gateway` objects since I want the Apache httpClient, using `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`.  This excludes defining a `rest-template` attribute on the `http:outbound-gateway`.  Can the `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` approach work this way?  Or will I need to subclass the factory and produce a `HttpClientRequest` with an `execute()` method that does the logging?  Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The `ClientHttpRequestFactory` is a part of the `RestTemplate` as well. so, you just move that your `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` configuration to the `RestTemplate` along side with that `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` and inject into an `http:outbound-gateway` only that `RestTemplate`.