# Spring-Integration AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice with webflux/reactive: does this introduce a synchronous process?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-webflux, reactive, declarative

I've implemented an advice handler attached to `outbound-gateway` components in order to be able to long outgoing HTTP requests before/after.  Originally, this was for a Spring-Integration project using MVC/servlet underpinnings.  (Original question: [Logging http request in Spring integration http outbound gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690843/logging-http-request-in-spring-integration-http-outbound-gateway?noredirect=1&lq=1) )

We are attempting a migration to `webflux`/`reactive` which means that we are using a `webflux:outbound-gateway` in lieu of a `http:outbound-gateway`.

The advice handler is an *around* call in the `doInvoke()` method:

```java
public class MyLogger extends AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice {

   // ...

   @Override
   protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message( 
   {

      // ... logging before the call ...

      Object result = callback.execute();

      // ... logging after the call ...

      return result;
   }

}
```

Whereas I understand that the `webflux:outbound-gateway` call itself is supposed to be asynchronous (i.e. no threads waiting on a response), it would seem to me that the advice handler itself must be implemented synchronously (i.e. thread awaiting the response).  Am I understanding correctly?  Is the advice handler adding synchronicity that wouldn't otherwise be there?

Thanks for any insights on this point.

Comment: It won't block, but it won't do what you want; the result will be a `Mono`, which will be completed later.

Comment: OK, I see.  I guess that I'll be looking for an equivalent to advice handling for logging  outbound http responses.  Thanks.

Comment: OK, I see, using ```share()``` as you mentioned in the sister post.  Thanks.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74537523/spring-integration-how-to-inspect-a-http-response-within-an-abstractrequesthand/74537804#74537804

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `ReactiveRequestHandlerAdvice` for this particular use-case to wrap a reply `Mono` with anything you'd like: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#reactive-advice